# "No one is born hating..." vs. "No one is born to hate..."

Tags: meaning, differences, infinitives

> “No one is born hating another person because of the color of his
>   skin, or his background, or his religion. People must learn to hate,
>   and if they can learn to hate, they can be taught to love, for love
>   comes more naturally to the human heart than its opposite.”

Source: Nelson Mandela, *[Long Walk to Freedom](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/111810-no-one-is-born-hating-another-person-because-of-the)*

**Why can't it be "No one is born *to hate* another…"?**

Comment: It can be.  This is English -- there's no rule that there can be only one way to express a thought.  But note that there are subtle differences in meaning between the two options.

Comment: But will there be a change in meaning?

Comment: Yes, a subtle change in meaning. See the answer by @Ian MacDonald. In English "born to X"  is used idiomatically to state a purpose or destiny for someones life and is not necessarily literal. Saying the baby is not born hating means that hating needs to be learned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing stopping it from being as you write, but the words were chosen by Nelson Mandela to evoke a certain meaning. Here, he evokes a state of being. A newborn *acting* as soon as it is born. Had he chosen "to hate", then there is less finality to the statement.

Consider:

> This baby was born to hate.
>   This baby *will hate at some point in the future*.

vs

> This baby was born hating.
>   This baby *is actively hating from the moment of birth*.